# Cant feed my data on the list C# Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, json, xaml, xamarin.forms, deserialization

For some reason, I can't get my data to feed my existing XAML list.

XAML

```
 <ListView x:Name="DList" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                   <Image  x:Name="img" Source="{Binding Image}"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                                 </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

MODEL 1

```
public class Model 
    {
         public List<ImageUrl> Image { get; set; }

    }

 public class ImageUrl 
    {
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
```

Model2 (This is the model I get if I convert the JSON data to c#)

```
public class Image
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public object links { get; set; }
    public object linkTemplates { get; set; }
}

public class Breed
{

    public Image image { get; set; }
    public object links { get; set; }
    public object linkTemplates { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Breed> breeds { get; set; }
    public object links { get; set; }
    public object linkTemplates { get; set; }
}
```

GETDATA

```
 if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(data);

                      }
```

data is correct, I received what I need. however, is on var response that it breaks.

Comment: you are binding your Image to a List<ImageUrl> instead of an individual ImageUrl.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: What is `ImageUrl` seems like a custom class to me

Comment: I am expecting a list of images that will be displayed in the list. please see the class on my updated code.

Comment: what exception does it throw when this breaks on the var?

Comment: jus a null exception. so, the data comes fine in var data, is when it gets to deserialized it breaks as null. I do think the model may be the issue. but what else would I use to deserialized a bunch of images into the list?

Comment: I update the model for clarity  @G.hakim

Comment: The shouldn't your deserialization look something like this : `response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);`

Answer (score 0):

If your code breaks in on `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` , you haven't properly created the class according to your json string, or it may not desirialize to `List<Model>` at all. My guess would be that you need to have some class that has a `List<Model>` field and use it to desirialize the json, that is the most common error.